# How to validate an HTML page generated entirely from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

With an entirely JavaScript-generated HTML page, how can I validate the page's HTML the browser is actually using, instead of the JavaScript that initially loaded?

Comment: As you're aiming for a website and not a webpage, I'd use Node.js/express on the serverside. That lets you write the backend in javascript. Then you can also generate your html there, using one of the many template-engines around. When you've succesfully installed node, https://github.com/robrighter/node-boilerplate should put you on the right track. If you opt for using coffeescript you also get something that *compiles into javascript*. Let your coworker chew on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to demonstrate that JS is a "real" language, then you would probably be better off not using a browser as the foundation. A [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) server would allow you to generate an HTML document (using document.write if you like, but DOM is an option (and people have [used client side libraries to manipulate a document in node](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/05/running-yui-3-server-side-with-node-js/).

Since the JS runs on the server, you can get the actual source from the browser via view-source or point the validator directly at the URI (so long as it is either public or you install [a local copy](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) of the validator)

Answer (score 2):

Load the site in Firefox with Firebug installed. Fire up the "HTML" view and rightclick on the `<html>` node and select "copy HTML".

Answer (score 1):

The closest you get using JavaScript:

```
var generatedHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
//Retrieves everything within the (missing)HTML tags.
//The only missing parts are DOCTYPE and the <html> itself

var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
txt.style.cssText = "width:99%;height:99%;position:fixed;z-index:999;top:0;left:0";
txt.value = generatedHTML;
txt.ondblclick = function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this)};
//Adding a simple function to easily remove the textarea once finished

document.body.appendChild(txt);
```

Bookmarklet (I have slightly adjusted the code to be compact):

```
javascript:void(function(){var t=document.createElement("textarea");t.style.cssText = "width:99%;height:99%;position:fixed;z-index:999;top:0;left:0";t.value=document.documentElement.innerHTML;txt.ondblclick=function(){t.parentNode.removeChild(t)};document.body.appendChild(t)})()
```

1. Focus the generated textarea
2. Manually add the DOCTYPE + `<html>` tags
3. Copy the contents of the textarea to the validator at: http://validator.w3.org/#validate-by-input